# Wait Process Until Start c#

Tags: c#

i need Wait Process Until Start in c#

Like : `ProcessWait("notepad.exe")` in Autoit

https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ProcessWait.htm

Comment: It would help if you gave an example of what you have already tried, that isn't working...

Answer (score 2):

More info here: [Process Information and Notifications using WMI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12138/Process-Information-and-Notifications-using-WMI)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;

namespace Test
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var queryString =
                "SELECT TargetInstance " +
                "FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 " +
                "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' " +
                "AND TargetInstance.Name LIKE 'notepad.exe'";

            var scope = @"\\.\root\CIMV2";

            var watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, queryString);
            watcher.EventArrived += watcher_EventArrived;
            watcher.Start();
            Process.Start("notepad.exe");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Notepad has been started");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Szer *** i Try this but not work

Comment: @ahmeddzcomahmed do you got any exceptions? What part of this doesnt work?

Comment: http://www.shy22.com/upfiljpg/zim10788.jpg

Comment: @ahmeddzcomahmed Project -> Add Reference -> Assemblies -> Framework -> Check System.Management -> Press OK.

Comment: @ahmeddzcomahmed I think you should read some book about C#. This error is trivial.